# Plaintext shown behind recyclerview

Tags: java, android

I was wondering, is there a way to set the plaintext infront of my recyclerview?

I have this textfield:

[image]

When i click this field in the app It's located under the recyclerview, so i can't see what I'm typing:

[image]

**XML EditText (Plaintext)**

```java
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/edit_hint_text"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/CloseApp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is,On the design view drag and drop your edit text under your layout

so it would be like this:

[image]

My English is not my main language so sorry if my grammar is too bad.